# ArangoDB - Optimize Intersection of Multiple Queries

Tags: optimization, query-optimization, intersection, arangodb, aql

I have 4 queries to get the INTERSECTED result from them and do a nested FOR on the next line.
Is there a way to optimize this query?

```
Query string:
 LET c0 = (FOR attr IN products_attributes
     FILTER attr.key == "nt1" AND attr.value >= 0 AND attr.value <= 5
 RETURN attr.productId)
 LET c1 = (FOR attr IN products_attributes
     FILTER attr.key == "st1" AND attr.value == "test str"
 RETURN attr.productId)
 LET c2 = (FOR attr IN products_attributes
     FILTER attr.key == "mlt1" AND attr.value == "mo1"
 RETURN attr.productId)
 LET c3 = (FOR attr IN products_attributes
     FILTER attr.key == "mlt1" AND attr.value == "mo2"
 RETURN attr.productId)
 LET collections = INTERSECTION(c0, c1, c2, c3)
 FOR pid IN collections
     FOR p IN products
         FILTER p._key == pid AND "test" IN p.st AND "product" IN p.st
         SORT p.date DESC
         LIMIT 0, 10
         RETURN p

Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType            Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode          1   * ROOT
  8   SubqueryNode           1     - LET c0 = ...   /* const subquery */
  2   SingletonNode          1       * ROOT
 40   IndexNode              1         - FOR attr IN products_attributes   /* persistent index scan */
  6   CalculationNode        1           - LET #21 = attr.`productId`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: attr : products_attributes */
  7   ReturnNode             1           - RETURN #21
 15   SubqueryNode           1     - LET c1 = ...   /* const subquery */
  9   SingletonNode          1       * ROOT
 41   IndexNode              0         - FOR attr IN products_attributes   /* persistent index scan */
 13   CalculationNode        0           - LET #25 = attr.`productId`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: attr : products_attributes */
 14   ReturnNode             0           - RETURN #25
 22   SubqueryNode           1     - LET c2 = ...   /* const subquery */
 16   SingletonNode          1       * ROOT
 42   IndexNode              0         - FOR attr IN products_attributes   /* persistent index scan */
 20   CalculationNode        0           - LET #29 = attr.`productId`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: attr : products_attributes */
 21   ReturnNode             0           - RETURN #29
 29   SubqueryNode           1     - LET c3 = ...   /* const subquery */
 23   SingletonNode          1       * ROOT
 43   IndexNode              0         - FOR attr IN products_attributes   /* persistent index scan */
 27   CalculationNode        0           - LET #33 = attr.`productId`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: attr : products_attributes */
 28   ReturnNode             0           - RETURN #33
 30   CalculationNode        1     - LET collections = INTERSECTION(c0, c1, c2, c3)   /* simple expression */
 39   IndexNode              1     - FOR p IN products   /* persistent index scan */
 35   CalculationNode        1       - LET #37 = p.`date`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: p : products */
 31   EnumerateListNode    100       - FOR pid IN collections   /* list iteration */
 44   CalculationNode      100         - LET #35 = (("product" in p.`st`) && (p.`_key` == pid))   /* simple expression */   /* collections used: p : products */
 34   FilterNode           100         - FILTER #35
 36   SortNode             100         - SORT #37 DESC
 37   LimitNode             10         - LIMIT 0, 10
 38   ReturnNode            10         - RETURN p

Indexes used:
 By   Type         Collection            Unique   Sparse   Selectivity   Fields               Ranges
 40   persistent   products_attributes   true     false            n/a   [ `key`, `value` ]   ((attr.`key` == "nt1") && (attr.`value` >= 0) && (attr.`value` <= 5))
 41   persistent   products_attributes   true     false            n/a   [ `key`, `value` ]   ((attr.`key` == "st1") && (attr.`value` == "test str"))
 42   persistent   products_attributes   true     false            n/a   [ `key`, `value` ]   ((attr.`key` == "mlt1") && (attr.`value` == "mo1"))
 43   persistent   products_attributes   true     false            n/a   [ `key`, `value` ]   ((attr.`key` == "mlt1") && (attr.`value` == "mo2"))
 39   persistent   products              false    false            n/a   [ `st[*]` ]          ("test" in p.`st`)

Optimization rules applied:
 Id   RuleName
  1   move-calculations-up
  2   move-filters-up
  3   interchange-adjacent-enumerations
  4   move-calculations-up-2
  5   move-filters-up-2
  6   use-indexes
  7   remove-filter-covered-by-index
  8   remove-unnecessary-calculations-2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need an intersection, then you could simply combine the subqueries into a single with four `FILTER` clauses, which act like a natural `AND`.

```py
LET collections = (
    FOR attr IN products_attributes
        FILTER attr.key == "nt1" AND attr.value >= 0 AND attr.value <= 5
        FILTER attr.key == "st1" AND attr.value == "test str"
        FILTER attr.key == "mlt1" AND attr.value == "mo1"
        FILTER attr.key == "mlt1" AND attr.value == "mo2"
        RETURN attr.productId
)
```

You might have to create an index with all of those columns, but it should work.  Otherwise, you could reduce subsequent datasets by limiting based on the previous. This is especially useful if the search crosses collections or indexing is not possible/rational:

```py
LET c0 = (
    FOR attr IN products_attributes
        FILTER attr.key == "nt1" AND attr.value >= 0 AND attr.value <= 5
        RETURN attr.productId
)
LET c1 = (
    FOR attr IN products_attributes
        FILTER attr.productId in c0
        FILTER attr.key == "st1" AND attr.value == "test str"
        RETURN attr.productId
)
LET c2 = (
    FOR attr IN products_attributes
        FILTER attr.productId in c1
        FILTER attr.key == "mlt1" AND attr.value == "mo1"
        RETURN attr.productId
)
LET c3 = (
    FOR attr IN products_attributes
        FILTER attr.productId in c2
        FILTER attr.key == "mlt1" AND attr.value == "mo2"
        RETURN attr.productId
)
```

Comment: this gives me an empty result

Comment: @zero.zero.seven, maybe you could provide more information, especially before down-voting a response.  Kinda makes people not want to help you.